# Understanding an expectation formula

Tags: expected-value, cumulative-distribution-functions

Consider a puddle of water which evaporates at random points over time. Let $f(x,t)$ be the fraction of evaporated water at site $x$ on the puddle at a time $t$ after the start of evaporation. I want to calculate the expected time of evaporation $t_E(x)$ at a site $x$. Is that simply given by
$$
t_E(x)=\int_0^\infty t \frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}\,dt
$$
since $f$ can be seen as the CDF of the process? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The fraction of water evaporated is not the CDF of the distribution of water fractions of some random process. For example, consider a linearly increasing $f(x,t) = t$ on $[0, 1]$, and constant $1$ thereafter. The expected time of evaporation is exactly $1$, while your formula would give you $1/2$.

Comment: Note that I am asking the expected time at position x, not of the whole domain. In your example, at a random position, I'd expect to wait half that time, i.e, 1/2.

Comment: No, in my example, $x$ does not matter. You can think of it as an infinite puddle. In other words, the fraction $f$ increases the same everywhere, so at all $x$ the expected evaporation time is the same, $t = 1$.